# Why is Blender muting the first split second of sound in the rendered video file?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, audio, encoding

To replicate:

1. Render a video sequence with an audio strip at the beginning.
   [image: blender sequencer and settings]
2. Extract the audio from the video file using ffmpeg:

   `ffmpeg -i blenderoutput.mp4 audio.wav`
3. Load the audio file in Audacity and look at the first instant in the waveform
   [image: waveform in audacity]

This is not a bug in ffmpeg, I tried it with other videos that have audio throughout, it did not silence the first split second.

Is this a bug in Blender or is there some flag/feature I have to toggle?

Comment: Perhaps Blender is not demuxing correctly, try transcoding the footage to a less compressed codec.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the audio clip in blender so that it starts at frame 1.

To do this, select your audio clip and press g.

Comment: Oh I did that before. The only reason I moved it to the middle like that is to be certain that its not the beginning of the audio file that is silent. Still the same problem.